# Firestore FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded. Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore as a backend for my ReactJS app and I'm using `writeBatch` method to add quite a number of data (up to about 1200 objects). This is my code:

```js
export async function batchAddProduct(data) {
  const batches = [];
  data.forEach((datum, i) => {
    if (i % 500 === 0) {
      batches.push(writeBatch(db));
    }

    const productRef = doc(collection(db, "product"));
    const batch = batches[batches.length - 1];
    batch.set(productRef, datum);
  });

  return await Promise.all(batches.map((batch) => batch.commit()))
    .then(() => {
      return { data: true, error: null };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { data: null, error: err };
    });
}
```

This works however only for the first time. When I apply this function, it adds all the documents to Firestore and on my usage page, it says that I have done a write up to `1.2K` which I think is correct since I'm adding that amount of data. However, after that, I deleted them, because I wanted to give them another try, so on my usage page, it shows that I have also done deletion up to `1.2K`. Now, if I try to upload/add data again using the same function and the same amount of data, it throws me 2 errors as such:

```
Firestore (9.15.0): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded.

Firestore (9.15.0): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
```

I have also waited for about 12 hours, to see if it would reset. Is there a hard limit for the maximum amount of data for a day (24h)?

Another thing I have tried is splicing the data, where I loop the function multiple times with only a maximum of 500 objects at a time. But this still throws me the same error.

Comment: It might take a while for the usage to update on Firebase console. The daily quota resets on midnight PST.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a hard limit for a maximum amount of data for a day (24h)?

Yes. If you're using the Spark Plan, you can perform up to 20,000 writes per day. If you reach the quota, the writes will start to fail.

Please remember, that Firebase quotas are reset daily at midnight (Pacific time). According to your timezone, it may also differ. If you're located in the EU, it may actually be in the middle of the day. So if you reach the daily limitation, you need to wait until the "next" day, or you can update to the Blaze Plan.

One thing that you should take into consideration would be to not keep your Firebase console open, as it is considered another Firestore client that reads data. So you'll be billed for the reads that are coming from the console.

Comment: What if I don't use the Spark plan?

Comment: If you're using the Blaze (paid) Plan, there are limitatins.

Comment: It turns out I'm using Spark Plan, and I'm still confused why I'm getting the error I stated in the question even though I have not reached 20K writes in a day.

Comment: There is no way you can get that error message without reaching the maximum limit. Most likely you're writing to Firestore from some other parts of your code. Try to isolate the write operation and if you get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today whilst working with a react application.

When implementing the functionality for a comments section using Firestore, my addComment() function was firing every time the input value changed. This resulted in heaps of new comments being stored unnecessarily in the backend(firebase), causing me to max out the quota of the Spark plan very quickly.

Theres probably some function being fired way to many times during input, or data retrieval/storage. Check the functions that retrieve/set/save values/data to the backend.